# Ember Data: Observing associated models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been working on implementing tagging with rails and ember, based on this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging

I've setup an ember-data model with a `tagList` property, which I'd like to set every time a tag changes (using the following `setTagList` method):

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  tags: DS.hasMany('App.Tag'),
  tagList: DS.attr('string'),

  setTagList: function() {
    if(this.get('tags.length')) {
      var tagList = this.get('tags').map(function(tag) {
        return tag.get('name');
      }).join(', ');
      this.set('tagList', tagList);
    }
  }.observes('isLoaded', 'tags', 'tags.@each.name')
});
```

The first error I ran into was:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of null
```

Which I believe is as a result of observing `tags` and `tags.@each.name`. I've also read that there may be [issues with observing nested properties](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/541).

Secondly, by removing those dependencies to leave `.observes('isLoaded')`, the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `materializingData` on <App.Post:ember283:1> while in state rootState. Called with undefined
```

Which is caused by any call to `this.get('tags')`.

See the JSBin: http://jsbin.com/iyoyax/7/edit

Can anyone advise how I might observe an associated model to set another attribute on the same model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see some unusual things here. Why do you have a `setTagList` observer? Should it be setting the `tagList` property (it's not doing that currently)? And if so, why not make `tagList` a computed property?

Comment: I've updated the example to include setting the tagList property. It cannot be a computed property because it is persisted (and therefore needs to be a `DS.attr`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your case isn't specifically working, but I'd be willing to bet that using `ember-data-latest` with `ember rc2` has something to do with it.

Your code seems fine. Here's an fiddle that is working: http://jsfiddle.net/DBtu6/5/

The only changes I made were to use rc6 with ember-data-latest and to change your `map` function to `mapProperty`.

I also used JSFiddle instead of JSBin because JSBin because I couldn't figure out how to use the latter's console and I was just more familiar with fiddle. Hope this helps.